# plt.show() gives some response in IPython but not in Visual Studio Code

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, anaconda, ipython, pytorch

I'm new to ML & AI in general, but I'm attempting to make sure I installed everything properly first before I do any real experimentation. I've been following a tutorial of sorts and I'm currently experiencing something strange.

[image: I'm encountering something Strange Right now.]
It appears that when you install Anaconda to make it easier to get Pytorch, it also installs IPython. I'm not entirely sure what it is but I assume its some sort of IDE as it can run code. I noticed by following the tutorial that **plt.plot(a)** doesn't spit out any response when I run the code in Visual Studio Code. However, the next line **plt.show()** works and spits out the expected graph image. I'm really confused about what is happening here. Is it because the line with the red icon in IPython symbolizes something internal that visual studio code doesn't print out? Also I noticed that in VSC that I have to have Anaconda 5.2.0 on the lower left instead of Python 3.7(64 bit). Is it because pytorch is only accessible though Anaconda when I installed pytorch with Anaconda? Should I just leave it at Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

IPython directly prints the return of a statement to the console. This is useful e.g. when typing `5*3` and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, you directly see the result instead of needing to type `print(5*3)` as in a script. The return of `plt.plot(a)` is list of `Line2D` objects. Hence IPython will print that line for you.

You may use a semicolon (`;`) to suppress output of a statement in IPython. E.g. `5*3;` would not show the result.

[image]

So if that line bothers you, you may type `plt.plot(a);` not to see it.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that/